# Read .xlsx and .xls data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, import-from-excel

I want to read the data of .xlsx or .xls file in codeigniter. I have read the other questions related it but nothing works. I have used phpexcel, reader but with no luck. In my project i give the option to upload excel file then i want to read the data and insert it in the database.

**Now i am using phpExcel library I have wrote:**

```
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $reader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $path=(FCPATH.'uploads/productfile/'.$_FILES['upload_file']['name']);
    $excel=$reader->load($path);
    $sheet=$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    for($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++)
    {
      $col1= $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();
      $col2= $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();
      $col3= $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue();
      var_dump($col1);
    }
```

**but it display :**

> Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'You tried to set
>   a sheet active by the out of bounds index: 0. The actual number of
>   sheets is 0 Please give me some example code.

**The error**
[image]
Please give me some example code:

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your code and results, and you'll have a far greater chance of getting a good answer to your question.

Comment: I did many things i have used phpexcel but in that i can not upload xlsx file and many error came. then i used phpreaded but same not done. so have removed all. Now i want to do it from beginning as per given idea.

Comment: the error you added is because the path you provided is invalid. The file you are trying to open is not in that path from the root folder. Adapt the path I have suggested in my answer to the real one you have

Comment: This library is extinct. The new version is called PHPSpreadsheet: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to all** for your suggestion:
 **I got the solution :**

```
$file_data = $this->upload->data();
$file_path =  './uploads/productfile/'.$file_data['file_name'];
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName = $file_path; 
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);  // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet
for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
{                   
    'product'=$allDataInSheet[$i]["C"],
    'brand'=$allDataInSheet[$i]["I"],
    'standard'=$allDataInSheet[$i]["J"],
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer where you got the idea from. It looks like you took most from @KSP's answer, so you should credit him.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
 $sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

This will return you an array of the current active sheet.Hope this helps.

Comment: where i should add this line?

Comment: replace $sheet=$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); with $sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true); and also you need to edit your FOR loop as this will return you an ARRAY not an OBJECT

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by a wrong initialization of the PHPexcel reader functionalities I suppose. 
I usually do something like this to get the data from an excel:

```
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$filename = '../uploads/product/abc.xls';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    $total_rows = $highestRow-1;

    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    //id
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row);
        $id = $cell->getValue();
        if(is_null($id)){$id = '#';}
    }
```

Comment: HI i have tried you code but i got the error like Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open abc.xls for reading! File does not exist

Comment: what error do you get? Anyway please note that you have to adapt my example to your environment!

Comment: i get the error : ---"Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open abc.xls for reading!"---

Comment: Then you have an issue with the file. Where is the file? Does apache user have right to read that folder? Is the file coming from a form? Please be more specific please

Comment: yes i have uploaded the file in uploads/product folder. I am giving option to upload the file and all files are saving in uploads/product directory

Comment: should i need to change anything in this ---" $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);"--- line(file path or any thing)????

Comment: thanks but still i get an error i have added that screen shot in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This extension of PHPExcel_IOFactory has issues with symbols like ™ Trademark, Copy Right, Degree etc.

You can't read a particular block if it contains such special characters.

Comment: Please explain how this could trigger the error `You tried to set a sheet active by the out of bounds index: 0.`.

Comment: No just put trademark symbol or copyright symbol in CSV format file and try to read it with PHPExcel_IOFactory this will not read the symblos

Comment: That's nice to know but it does not answer my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

This code segment works for me,

```
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $reader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $path= "./media/customer_exports/data-1558003506.xlsx";
        $excel=$reader->load($path);

        $sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
        $arrayCount = count($sheet); 
        for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++)
        {                   
            echo $sheet[$i]["A"].$sheet[$i]["B"].$sheet[$i]["C"];
        }
```